# Cognos report get crazy during Drill-through to another report

Tags: cognos

I have a Cognos Express version 9.5 report with Drill-Through defined on a list column that open a second report passing it the coresponding data item value as parameter.

The second report open correctly showing data filtered as it should using the parameter received during drill-Through.

The problem is that the second report take forever to open and freeze my browser during various seconds... This is strange because this problem happen only when opening second report with drill-through and not when opening it directly filling in the optional parameter with a prompt...

Using browser debugger (f12) I noticed that `http://my_server/p2pd/servlet/dispatch` is called hundred of times before opening the second report and this is what is causing the browser to freeze...

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Are both source and target reports in the same package?

Comment: Yes both reports use the same package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating my report to COGNOS 10.1.1 solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'Drill Through Assistant' to help with debugging your Drill-Through definition.

[Here is a link to IBM site describing how to use the Drill through assistant.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cx/v9r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cra.9.5.0.doc/ug_cra_id23558AccessDTAssistant.html)

Comment: Using the Drill Through Assistant show me information about the related report and passed parameter... Everything seemS ok except that even right clicking on the link to open the assistant is very slow... various second are needed to open the contextual menu and I see dozens of calls (POST) to p2pd/servlet/dispatch...

Comment: Try disabling the drill through and recreating it.